# PHP hangs when run from CMD

Tags: php, windows

I have PHP added as an env variable - set to C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3, but when I run `php` from CMD the window locks up and it just hangs indefinitely. When run "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\php.exe" directly then the interactive shell starts normally.

No errors in the event log. Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 redistributable is installed. No other versions of PHP present (though there was an old version installed historically).

Comment: _I have PHP added as an env variable_ Please show us how you did this

Comment: System Properties>Environment Variables>append file path; C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run PHP in an interactive mode you need to pass the `-a` flag

example :

`php -a`  or `C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\php.exe -a`

Running both `php` or `C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\php.exe` will cause the **terminal** **to** **hang** and a **CLI php process to start**

You can quit the process by pressing `Ctrl + C`

Comment: OK, this does explain the problem and is me misunderstanding how IIS invokes PHP when needed by a site. Sorry, I am fairly new.

I was hoping this would be the crux of the problem but it seems PHP is installed and working correctly. Now I need to figure out why my Cisco phone directory site is unable to use this version of PHP.  Yay!

Thank you, lotfio.

Answer (score 0):

Running only the `php` command will cause this problem.
`php -r` command can be used to run PHP code on CLI. Example: `php -r 'echo "Hello world!";'`